# Set where clause on field

Tags: jpa, annotations, where-clause

I have a base entity that holds a enum field called State.

```
public enum State {

    DELETED(0),
    ACTIVE(1)
    ;

    private int value;

    private State(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }

}
```

Is there a JPA annotated way to set the where clauses of the generated queries to retrieve only entities that the state field is "ACTIVE"?
The reason is that if i have an entity "A" that holds a list of entities "B", when i retrieve from the DB an instance of "A" and initialize it, i want the list of "B" to hold only the entities where the State filed is "ACTIVE"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no filter or where annotations in JPA and there is no way to filter collection entities using annotations.

I suggest you retrieving A entities and fetching only active B entities.

Comment: There is "@Filter" and "@Where" annotations that can be used, for the given question you can have a look at http://www.concretepage.com/hibernate/hibernate-filter-and-filterjointable-annotation-example

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard way to do this in JPA.

One method might be to create a view that filters the table and map to the view instead of the table.

If you are using EclipseLink you can use @AdditionalCriteria

http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/a_additionalcriteria.htm#additionalcriteria

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you do this with database views. Access the underlying table containing all entities including the soft deleted entities and access a view for the non-deleted entities

Answer (score -1):

Use  `@Filter` as

```
 @Filter(name, condition)
```

or `@Where` as

```
 @where(state = STATE.ACTIVE.getValue())
```

Comment: i am not using JPA 2. my maven dependency is:
`<dependency>
   <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
   <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.2</version>
  </dependency>`

Comment: are `@Filter` and `@Where` JPA annotations or Hibernate annotations? i need to be pure JPA and i didn't find these annotations in `javax.persistence` packages

Comment: Thank you for your answer. maybe do you know any pure JPA annotation or any other pure JPA method (other then writing the JPQL) to achieve this?